# Permission error while adding new physical device to QEMU under libvirt?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I'm trying to add a USB camera to QEMU so that it can be virtualized for guest OS. I've added the following item in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf.

```
cgroup_device_acl = [
"/dev/null", "/dev/full", "/dev/zero",
...
"/dev/rtc", "/dev/hpet", **"/dev/video0",**
]
```

Also, I've mounted the cgroup controller as below.

```
mkdir /dev/cgroup
mount -t cgroup none /dev/cgroup -o devices
```

But I'm getting "Permission denied" error(13) in the following code.

```
fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
```

Strange observation is that this error only happens when I use Virt-manager(libvirt). The issue disappears when QEMU is run by command-line.
Is there anyway to give all the device access to QEMU in libvirt? Or any more step to check for libvirt/qemu.conf?

Comment: Since I'm only interested in developing QEMU back-end driver not in Linux security, any engineering configuration solution will do.

Answer (score 0):

Very long shot, but did you had a chance to go through this [page on libvirt docs](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Guest_won%27t_start_-_warning:_could_not_open_/dev/net/tun_%28%27generic_ethernet%27_interface%29?)?

It's a different issue, but it's being stated there, that disabling selinux is one of the steps required.

Comment: I've followed the steps in the page you pointed above but it didn't work. I've tried every steps except the "selinux" step because I've never enabled it in my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

One simple work-around to give the access right is to change the ownership of the device to libvirt-qemu. I've done the following command and Libvirt can now open the device all right.

```
sudo chown libvirt-qemu /dev/video0
```